# Minimising or switching to other window during web-driver test run will fail the test case?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Issue is only if i minimize chrome browser manually by clicking '-' icon or switch to code editor or any other window in my system, test case is failing with below error ?

```
 NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Any help would be appreciated.